# Add ImageView @ the end of a CollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uicollectionview

I created a CollectionViewController using Storyboards and made the adjustments by code and now I need to add a ImageView at the bottom of the screen that takes the whole width of the view.

I tried using Storyboards to do it, but it didn't work, if I add it programmatically, where and how should I do it?

```
import UIKit
import Device_swift

class MenuCentralCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {


    //data source

    let deviceType = UIDevice.current.deviceType



    // MARK: ViewController life cycle

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let layout = collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 310 / 2 - 37.5, height: 150)
    }

    // MARK: - UICollectionviewDataSource

    override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 8
    }

    private struct Storyboard {
        static let CellIdentifier = "MenuCell"
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: Storyboard.CellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell

        return cell
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `UIViewController` and add `UICollectionView` as subview yourself. With this approach you can add any subviews with any frames, not only fullscreen `UICollectionView.

Comment: Yeah, if I knew how to do that, I would not be asking it here.